# After booting Ubuntu on USB every files lost from desktop on next boot

Tags: usb

I have booted using “Try Ubuntu without Installing” after booting from LiveUSB, I am copying some files from harddisk to Ubuntu desktop, but on next boot I can't get those files.

Please help me how i can transfer files from other HDD Drive to my booted Ubuntu USB drive for later use.

Comment: Did you make USB a Startup Disk or did you install Ubuntu on USB?

Comment: I think its an start up disk, I just followed steps shown how to make bootable disk for ubuntu.

Comment: After reboot i use “Try Ubuntu without Installing” option to boot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how a Live USB or Live CD is expected to work. Each time that you boot from them it starts afresh. That said you have a couple of options:

- Copy the files to another place, like another USB pendrive or another hard drive.
- Configure your USB disk to be [persistent](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent). Usually you just need to select "Stored in reserved space" when creating the USB drive (see picture). If you need some alternatives, please check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201571/i-have-a-live-usb-of-lubuntu-and-want-to-make-it-persistent-to-the-same-usb-ca).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Javier, so its seems i have to format it again to make it persist, What tool will be good on windows 7

Comment: Unetbooting, see the question that I linked.