# Can I have Ubuntu, apps, and files on a USB

Tags: usb, lubuntu

Is it possible to use a USB to contain Ubuntu and a lightweight variant (Lubuntu) along with updates, files, documents, apps, etc? In other words, can I put everything on a USB so I can open my stuff on any computer?

Is that even possible?
If so, how is it done?
Would it be fast?

any info on the subject would be appreciated

Comment: *Is that even possible?* - Yes. *If so, how is it done?* - There's some questions about that here. *Would it be fast?* - It depends on how fast the USB is.

Comment: This question has been asked before


  http://askubuntu.com/a/201641/158420

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

Please check [this link](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). In my opinion it lets you do this in the most easy way:

1. Download Ubuntu distro (Lubuntu would be the lightest)
2. Download and run Unetbootin
3. Choose system *.iso image
4. Chose USB on which you wish to have Ubuntu, and remember to set option that uses some part of USB as system HDD.

And done.